# By trying to put a filename with [chunkhash] in webpack, returns an error

Tags: javascript, webpack, error-handling, configuration

By using `filename: dev ? '[name].js' : '[name].[chunkhash:8].js'`, in
webpack.config.js (in prod), i got the error

```
ERROR in chunk manifest [entry]
[name][chunkhash:8].js
Cannot use [chunkhash] for chunk in '[name][chunkhash:8].js' (use [hash] instead)
```

How should I use chunkhash correctly?

https://gist.github.com/blaadje/23340f9bf466e10c8e33e3ef4f207e74
For more infos about the cfg